# Sales Order Grid Filter issue with custom column - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

We have set the default timezone for admin as IST.

[image]

now, we added one column in sales order grid for CST date but the filter is not working as Expected.

[image]

While search with 20th Date only one record display instead of two.

[image]

Thanks,

Can anyone know how we can fix that??